# Mandar boton con tecla

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de hacer que mi código active un botón booleano con dos teclas. Estoy tratando de hacer que la tecla S y K envíen cada boton. Tengo el siguiente código, pero cuando lo intento correr, no se ejecuta.
Este es mi código HTML. Cada botón tiene una función que me da una marca de tiempo del clic, envía la página y guarda la opción que elija el participante (A o B).

```
<html>
    <body>

<p style="text-align: center;">
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" 
onclick="myFunction()" name="offer_accepted1" id="of1A" value="True">&nbsp;A</button> 
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large"
onclick="myFunction()" name="offer_accepted1" id="of1B" value="False">B</button>
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="timestamp1" value="0" />
{{ form.timestamp1.errors }}

 <input type="text" id="c1" name="c1" value="0" />
 {{ form.c1.errors }}

 <script>
var input = document.getElementById("of1A");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 75) {
 event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
});

var input = document.getElementById("of1B");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 83) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});


//The function that gives me a timestamp

function myFunction() {
  var n = Date.now();
  document.getElementById("c1").value = n;
   }

</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("myBtn").click();` no hay ningún elemento con ese ID.

Comment: Hola soy un poco nuevo usando JavaScript, me podrías indicar que debería hacer, lo elimino o lo cambio por el ID que tengo con mi marca de tiempo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Probablemente quieras reemplazar el `myBtn` por `of1A` y `of1B` en cada caso, si es que estoy entendiendo bien lo que querés hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenias el evento keyup en el botón, para que este evento ocurra tienes que hacer un foco en el botón y presionar alguna tecla, lo que no tendría utilidad. Hay que declararlo en el objeto window.
`addEventListener('keyup', function())`
o
`window.addEventListener('keyup', function())`.

Luego mandas a llamar a un método en un elemento DOM inexistente `document.getElementById("myBtn").click()`. Con esto seguramente estas queriendo que se clickee el boton para que se ejecute myFunction(), es mejor llamar a myFunction() desde el condicional del evento.

`if (event.keyCode === 75 || event.keyCode === 83)
            myFunction()`

El elemento DOM a que te refieres seguramente es el de ID "c1" ya que en este pones el Date.now().

Resumiendo código, se puede dejar el script así

```
<script>

    addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        if (event.keyCode === 75 || event.keyCode === 83)
            myFunction()
    })


    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("c1").value = Date.now();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hola Franco muchas gracias, el código funciona muy bien para conseguir timestamps cuando clickeamos S y K, mi pregunta es como hacer click en cada uno de los botones, es decir asociar 75 con el boton de la derecha y 83 con el botón de la izquierda.

Comment: Con condicionales. si event.key === 75 entonces es por que se quiso presionar el botón de ID "of1B", el de la derecha.

Comment: Sería algo como if event.key == 75  {
   document.getElementById("of1B").click();
  } Perdón la intensidad

Comment: Sí, hay mandas a clickear el botón de la derecha, para que se ejecute myFunction().

Comment: addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    if (event.keyCode === 75) {
   document.getElementById("if1A").click();
  }
 
   Intente con esto y al parecer no funciona

Comment: No es "if1A" es "of1A". Tienes que poner exactamente el ID de los botones.